# Help with reopening a question that was wrongly closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Although the iOS 5 SDK is still under NDA, automatic reference counting has been [publicly announced](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-June/015588.html) and the LLVM Web site has [public information](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) about it.

However, the NDA police is still downvoting and closing questions about ARC as being off-topic, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-automatic-reference-counting-in-ios-5-works).

Would you please vote to reopen it?

**The question has been reopened; thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I would.   It is has now been reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think, that question can be aligned with the following from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to be deemed off-topic, anyway:

> there is no actual problem to be solved

Maybe if you asked for something more specific. Again, from the FAQ, the first point of a question ought to be:

> a specific programming problem

*'Wondering exactly how it works'* could be considered too broad. Now that is has been reopened, I would provide some specificity, if I were you.

Comment: I’ve found an [interesting answer by Robert Harvey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106479/is-there-a-contradiction-in-the-faq/106484#106484) that’s a counterpoint to your reasoning. Also, [Stack Overflow’s FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) states that a ‘I would like others to explain ______ to me’ question is OK if it’s not a discussion/subjective question.